# problem with debug messages in rxconsole

Tags: ros, rosconsole, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have 2 computers: master and lowlevel. I log in master where I run roscore. I ssh to lowlevel to launch some nodes there. THe whole thing works fine so I guess the setup is configured properly.

I am trying to debug a node on the lowlevel computer, written in python. logdebug messages do not print anywhere: neither in the logfile, the screen or rxconsole.

In rxconsole, when I try to set the node's verbose level to debug, my node does not appear in the list of nodes.

If I init_node with log_level=rospy.DEBUG, the following message appears in the log file:
"Unable to report rosout: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?"
see complete log file here: http://pastebin.com/5sL91492

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12760/problem-with-debug-messages-in-rxconsole/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe the log level setting in `rxconsole` works for Python nodes.

I usually end up editing the script changing the message levels to INFO.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-11**:
How to override logging levels is documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging#Advanced:_Override_Logging_Configuration